# How can a function be called immediately after a pan gesture?

Tags: ios, swift3

Please know that I am new to Swift and IOS.  I am using a pan gesture to move a label.  When it is finished, I want to automatically add a new label.  I have tried to call a function at the end of the pan function, but the label that I moved gets moved off the screen, when the new label is added.  I have attempted to use "panGR.state.rawValue == 3",  "panGR.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended", and a timer - without success.  Please help.

Hopefully this is the code that is needed to explain the problem:

```
func initGestureRecognizers() {

    let panGR = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:
    #selector(ShapeView.didPan(_:)))
    addGestureRecognizer(panGR) 

}

func didPan(_ panGR: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    self.superview!.bringSubview(toFront: self)
    var size: CGFloat = 53
    var translation = panGR.translation(in: self)
    translation = translation.applying(self.transform)
    self.center.x += translation.x
    self.center.y += translation.y
    panGR.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)

    if panGR.state.rawValue == 1 { // save the last position
        let startX = self.center.x
        let startY = self.center.y
    }

    if panGR.state.rawValue == 3 {  // when move is finished

        // this will remove ability to move tile
        removeGestureRecognizer(panGR)

        // the following code should replace the moved tile,
        // with a new tile, but leave the moved tile where it is.

        // BUT - it moves the moved tile to coordinates (x=0,y=0), if 
        // the following 2 lines are executed.

        self.center.x = 0   
        self.center.y = 0

        // if the above 2 lines are not executed, the new tile
        // does not get displayed

        replaceMovedTile()

    }
}

func replaceMovedTile() {
        // position new tile
        let tapPoint = CGPoint(x: 46 + 22, y: 596 + 22)  
        let shapeView = ShapeView(origin: tapPoint)   
        addSubview(shapeView)
}
```

Comment: We would need more code, post code of your selector for pan gesture.

Comment: display your code then i can help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

addSubview is a function created for you?
If not, put self.view before

```
self.view.addSubview(shapeView)
```